# Formatting in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format in Google Spreadsheets and am unsure how to do the following:

- If column G is equal to “Yes” then it will format the entire row by changing to font to grey, italic and strike through the row.

I can set the format to change column G to grey font and grey background but cannot work out how to set the whole row to change the format. And is it possible to make the strike through?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what I think you want is not possible. The choice is to compromise on automation (eg filter ColumnG for "Yes" and format to suit) or to forego italic and strikethrough as the choice of fonts in conditional formatting at present is only for text colour.

You need to decide whether the font is to be grey or the cell background colour is to be grey (or both!) but assuming the former and that your row is of 26 columns something like this may suit:

[image]